# Prefer AAAA (IPv6) DNS lookups before A (IPv4) lookups

Tags: network-manager, dns, ipv6, resolv.conf, glibc

I want AAAA requests first as required by https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305#section-3

> Both queries SHOULD be made as soon after each other as possible, with
> the AAAA query made first

but I think it is not possible in Network Manager / glibc (resolv.conf). See also https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/252#issuecomment-580073819

Note: this is not about DNSv6 preference! I have already `nmcli connection modify CONNECTION ipv6.dns-priority 1` to prefer DNSv6!

EDIT: the same about Windows, yes, I know, I know ;)

Comment: A is IPv4  AAAA is IPv6. Defying RFCs is unwise.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I copied the question. Edited.))